# Mark as Answer multiple times

Tags: discussion

I just wanted to know that an answer may solve problem of many people but only one person who have asked question can mark it as correct answer. Is it possible to give an option to other people to mark it as answer instead of UpVote ? So this will show that for how many people it has solved the problem.

Comment: Oh can't imagine the arguments will come over meta because of this feature

Comment: Then users could just mark all answer's as accepted to gain reputation

Comment: Well i guess you can mark an answer only one time.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are proposing? Just an additional number beside each answer saying the number of community votes as "this solved my problem" it has? Aren't upvotes already likely to be well correlated with this?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly disagree with this feature. As it will cause a lot of arguments and disagreements between users regarding marking as an answer. Current answer marking strategy is optimal and best.

Also Looking at the upvotes, you can clearly see what the best answer is and since answers are ordered by votes by default, you get a good view of the better answers to the question.

Comment: Yes i know all this i was just asking if this is possible or not ?

Comment: If it is possible then you could have got many upvotes for your question. Down votes on meta is equal to disagreement by the users.